# Sql query to check if a given step is the last advanced step in the workflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the 2 following tables:

```
|_________________WORKFLOW__________________||___________STEP___________|
| ID_WORKFLOW | ID_STEP |     ID_OBJECT     || ID_STEP |  CODE  | LEVEL | 
|-------------|---------|-------------------||---------|--------|-------|
|     100     |    1    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_1 ||    1    | STEP_1 |   10  |
|     101     |    2    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_1 ||    2    | STEP_2 |   20  |
|     102     |    3    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_1 ||    3    | STEP_3 |   30  |
|     103     |    4    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_1 ||    4    | STEP_4 |   40  |
|     104     |    5    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_1 ||    5    | STEP_5 |   50  |
|     105     |    1    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_2 |----------------------------
|     106     |    2    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_2 |
|     107     |    3    | BUSNIESS_OBJECT_2 |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to query `WORKFLOW` table filtering on STEP->CODE column and having the last STEP->LEVEL.

For example, I'd like to get from workflow table workflows where STEP->CODE = 'STEP_3'.
In the result, I expect ID_WORKFLOW = 107. But not ID_WORKFLOW = 102. Because this one has an advanced step of 4 (ID_WORKFLOW = 103) It's STEP->LEVEL is greater than 40>30.

I don't know if it's possible to get the result using a simple sql query with some joins or if I need to definitely use a cursor for this.

Many thanks for your advices in advance,

Comment: [Please add text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), Also add RDBMS tag

Comment:  Please!! Never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. Please take the time to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and *spell check* your question - some BASIC effort is required here.

Comment: Many thanks for you feedback. I know much better now how to create tables in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, that you are looking for business objects at a particular step in the workflow, here is something you can try:

```
DECLARE @step table ( id_step int, code varchar(10), [level] int );
INSERT INTO @step ( id_step, code, [level] ) VALUES
    ( 1, 'STEP_1', 10 ),
    ( 2, 'STEP_2', 20 ),
    ( 3, 'STEP_3', 30 ),
    ( 4, 'STEP_4', 40 ),
    ( 5, 'STEP_5', 50 );

DECLARE @workflow table ( id_workflow int, id_step int, id_object varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO @workflow ( id_workflow, id_step, id_object ) VALUES
    ( 100, 1, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_1' ),
    ( 101, 2, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_1' ),
    ( 102, 3, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_1' ),
    ( 103, 4, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_1' ),
    ( 104, 5, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_1' ),
    ( 105, 1, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_2' ),
    ( 106, 2, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_2' ),
    ( 107, 3, 'BUSINESS_OBJECT_2' );

-- workflow id_step to query.
DECLARE @workflow_id_step int = 3;

-- return workflows currently at id_step 3.
SELECT
    *
FROM @workflow AS workflow
INNER JOIN @step AS step
    ON workflow.id_step = step.id_step
WHERE
    -- queried step
    workflow.id_step = @workflow_id_step
    -- exclude ID_OBJECT workflows that are further along than the queried @workflow_id_step
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @workflow AS w WHERE 
            w.id_object = workflow.id_object    -- important to join in the id_object value
            AND w.id_step > workflow.id_step    -- look for steps greater than the queried id_step
    )
ORDER BY
    workflow.id_object, workflow.id_workflow;
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
| id_workflow | id_step |     id_object     | id_step |  code  | level |
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
|         107 |       3 | BUSINESS_OBJECT_2 |       3 | STEP_3 |    30 |
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

**NOTES**

- I added a few comments to help understand the logic.
- Assumed your step `CODE` values are in sync with their `ID_STEP` values (**e.g.**, id_step: 1 = code: Step 1, etc.).
- Assumed individual workflows are grouped by `id_object`.

**UPDATE**

To filter based on a steps level instead...

```
-- return workflows currently at id_step 3 that do not have a greater step-level.
SELECT
    *
FROM @workflow AS workflow
INNER JOIN @step AS step
    ON workflow.id_step = step.id_step
WHERE
    -- queried step
    workflow.id_step = @workflow_id_step
    -- exclude ID_OBJECT workflows that are further along than the queried @workflow_id_step
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @workflow AS w 
        INNER JOIN @step AS s
            ON w.id_step = s.id_step
        WHERE 
            w.id_object = workflow.id_object    -- important to join in the id_object value
            AND s.[level] > step.[level]        -- look for steps with a greater level than the queried id_step level
    )
ORDER BY
    workflow.id_object, workflow.id_workflow;
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
| id_workflow | id_step |     id_object     | id_step |  code  | level |
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
|         107 |       3 | BUSINESS_OBJECT_2 |       3 | STEP_3 |    30 |
+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your kind help and comments :)

Comment: Regarding your first note:
Step **CODE** is more sync with **LEVEL** than **ID_STEP**. Maybe in the future, I'll have a new step: ID_STEP = 6 and LEVEL=15. So, advancing step from this one start at ID_STEP = 2.

Comment: Regarding your second note:
Yes individual workflows are grouped by id_object.

Comment: I think that your query seems to be fine. I just need to replace somewhere id_step with level and I think it should work. I understand the logic.
I try this tomorrow and I'll be back to you :)

Comment: This is just an example. You should have a good idea of how to move forward. My guess is you would switch the `> id_step` with `> level` if the step ids do not control the actual order.

Comment: @OHA, I added an update to base the exclusion on `level`.

Comment: critical_error, Oups! You shouldn't! :P (I'm just kidding)
I prefered to do this myself to refine my understanding :-)
Anyway thank you a lot four your kind help :-). Still not tested yet.

Comment: Hi critical_error, The query works perfectly. Many thanks for your kind help. Due to it, now I know how to deal with similary cases in the future.

Comment: critical_error, could you suggest please a significant title to this topic? The idea is to become easy to identify by others having the same need. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps something like "Check if a step is the current step in a workflow"?